# What is this plant with a long stem and tiny round, pointed leaves?

Tags: identification, houseplants, vines, stems

I have this house plant that was given to me, and I’m watering it as instructed, but it just keeps growing out its stem and only has tiny leaves. The leaves are small, round at the bottom and pointed at the top - they look kind of like teardrops. What plant is this?

[image]

Comment: A close up photo of the leaves would be helpful. Also, is that round brown thing in the pot part of the plant?

Answer (score 4):

Based on the big brown bulb and the stem I think it is a *Stephania erecta*. The baby leaves could look similar: [Stephania erecta Plant Care 4: Leaves!](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zIZrcukQy6k). Mature leaves will be more round but they still have a pointy part.

[image]